# Typescript compiler generates javascript even after compilation error

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to TypeScript and trying few basic stuffs. So I compile below `app1.ts` code

```
class Monster {
    constructor(name, initialPosition) {
        this.name = name;
        this.initialPosition = initialPosition; 
    }
}
```

I believe we can add any properties to class `Monster` on fly like we can do in JS. So `this.name` and `this.initialPosition` should be a valid way. But as soon as I compile the code it has thrown below errors

> app1.ts(3,14): error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type
>   'Monster'.
>
> app1.ts(4,14): error TS2339: Property 'initialPosition' does not exist
>   on type ' Monster'.

At this moment I thought we probably cannot add properties on fly (well, I got to know that we cannot do it like ECMA 6, we have to define properties - that's good) but when I check the generated JS it really surprised me. After compilation error it generated below JS code

```
var Monster = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Monster(name, initialPosition) {
        this.name = name;
        this.initialPosition = initialPosition;
    }
    return Monster;
}());
```

I am a bit confuse. Why after compilation error it generated JS? What actually going on.

Comment: ... who says it can't?

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12501/69850) (different SE site, but worth a read anyway)

Comment: @user202729 Ok if so, why it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some types of errors relate to type checking that allow the compiler to emit JS. Just because the typescript compiler can't prove the program is typesafe does not mean it will not run. If the code can run it will be outputted to JS (so type errors allow emit, but syntactic ones do  not)

There is a compiler option controlling this `--noEmitOnError`. You can read more [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)